# Extracting multiple substrings from a string using python

Tags: python, regex, string, csv

I have an xml string (which I am fetching from a CSV) here from which I need to identify the values and names from it. The logic I thought is to extract all strings which are in between of `>` and `</` for values and then remove the extracted substring which contains `<` or `>`

I am yet to think on how I can extract parameter name as well. I am using python.

Below is the xml string that I read from csv file.

```
<ServiceInstanceUpdateAck xmlns='http://www.loremipsum.com/'>
<Context>
    <Attribute name='Atri1'>A1</Attribute>
    <Attribute name='Atri2'>A2</Attribute>
    <Attribute name='Atri3'>A3</Attribute>
</Context>
<Operation>DEPROVISION</Operation>
<Status>SUCCESS</Status>
<Error message='No Error' majorErrorCode='E_NONE' minorErrorCode='E_NONE'/> 
<Service>
  <Id>11233334</Id>
</Service> 
</ServiceInstanceUpdateAck>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note: This is not a whole xml. It is a post body data that I am fetching from a CSV file. It is a string basically when I fetch it. So I cannot use XML parser here.

Comment: This is not a whole xml. This is a post body data of a request that I am fetching from a CSV file. So it is basically a string. and I cannot use XML parser here.

Comment: Why not use the XML parser of the post body data of your request?

Answer (score 3):

Since your data is simply XML you could just use an XML parser, documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: Just added a note in my question which makes it more clear. Not able to use xml parser here.

Comment: You can totally parse XML from a string, at least according to the documentation. That you do not know what the names are is fine, since you can access children recursively and access them using .tag and .attrib

Comment: Can you refer me to some example? I tried doing that with .tag and .attrib but wasn't successful.

Comment: I also want to add that parsing xml with regex is not really possible. (As has been stated many times on SO), here is a rather funny but good read: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML parser; [`xml.dom.minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) should suffice:

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom
>>> doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlString)
>>> for item in doc.getElementsByTagName("Attribute"):
...     print(item.getAttribute("name"))
...     print(item.childNodes[0].wholeText)
Atri1
A1
Atri2
A2
Atri3
A3
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I thought of using it but the problem is this is just one set of string. I have multiple set of strings which have different values. Using parser with hard-coded tag values will only work for one string and not for others.

Comment: @user2606665: You only need to know the names if you're looking for specific nodes. You can just as easily parse the whole tree recursively, something you can't do with regexes.

Comment: Actually nodes have different names in different strings. They aren't the same for all strings.

Comment: Yes, which makes the case for an XML parser even more. You don't need to know either the names of the nodes or the structure beforehand.

Comment: Alright. I now understand what you're trying to say. I'll try to use xml parser and let you know.

Comment: Hey, I went through python docs but was not able to understand it clearly. Can you point me to some example or article link if you know any?

Comment: I tried using your code mentioned above. It doesn't print anything for me. Is it because I am passing it as string?

Comment: The code works if `xmlString` contains the sample data you posted in your question.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I did debug and found I was reading another string. Yes, the code works now. But I am still not able to implement xml parsing of string :(